# How OpenSSH determine which sftp-server binary is linked to internal-sftp?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, sftp

I met a weird issue about setting up SFTP server by OpenSSH on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

These two lines are used in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to set SFTP server up, but no matter which line I use, `/var/log/auth.log` will report error as the following:

```
Nov 20 16:14:20 <user> sshd[34237]: Accepted password for <user> from 10.1.2.56 port 55028 ssh2
Nov 20 16:14:20 <user> sshd[34248]: subsystem request for sftp
Nov 20 16:14:20 <user> sshd[34248]: error: subsystem: cannot stat /usr/libexec/sftp-server: No such file or directory
Nov 20 16:14:20 <user> sshd[34248]: subsystem request for sftp failed, subsystem not found
```

When I run locate command to find which sftp-server binary are located, this is the output:

```
$ locate sftp-server
/usr/lib/sftp-server
/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
/usr/share/doc/openssh-sftp-server
/usr/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8.gz
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-sftp-server.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openssh-sftp-server.md5sums
```

I am not asking how to fix this problem. What I am curious about is how sshd determine which sftp-server binary should be used for internal-sftp sub-system, and why that is different from the output of locate command?

locate tells it should be 
`/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` or `/usr/lib/sftp-server`, but sshd always try to find `/usr/libexec/sftp-server` instead.

Could anyone provide some suggestion here? Any hint are appreciated.

Comment: Do you get that error with every SFTP connection? How exactly do you test this?

Comment: What version of OpenSSH is that?

Comment: Martin, yes. I got that error every time when I tried. I used this command: `sftp <user-name>@<server-ip>`, then I got this response in terminal
`subsystem request failed on channel 0`

Comment: OK, well, I'm, posting an answer to answer your titular question. Not that it helps you with your actual problem. But it may serve as an indication that you have a different problem that what you think.

Comment: Martin, thanks. I used a work round to avoid this problem. I copied sftp-server binary to `/usr/libexec/sftp-server`, then the problem was gone, but I want to find why this happens. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: What client are you using? IIRC, WinSCP has some oddities wrt invoking the sftp server after establishing a connection - do you get the same result using sftp from the command line on a Linux client?

Comment: Well, it does not happen because of `internal-sftp`. Has that been actually used, you would not get the problem. So I'd say that `sshd` is using a different `sshd_config` than the one you are looking at.

Comment: @symcbean OP is using `sftp`, see a comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`internal-sftp` is a keyword that makes OpenSSH `sshd` use an SFTP server that's included in (linked into) the `sshd` binary.

It does not refer to any external binary.

---

So if you use `internal-sftp`, the `sshd` should not look for any `sftp-server` binary. *What suggests that your `sshd_config` is actually not being used.*

Comment: Martin, I also doubted that, but it seemed not this issue. These are two sshd_config files that I found in the server, even I edited both, the problem was still there.  `$ sudo find / -name sshd_config
/usr/share/doc/openssh-client/examples/sshd_config
/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Run `sshd -T` to see what configuration is actually being used.

Comment: sshd uses /etc/ssh/sshd_config, but some other errors are reported. `$ sshd -t
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Disabling protocol version 2. Could not load host key
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.` Does that mean sshd restart fail?

Comment: Are you running it as a root? Also, it's `-T`, not `-t`.

Comment: Yes, I ran this command as root, but if I used -T, it reminded me invalid option. `$ sudo sshd -T
sshd: illegal option -- T
sshd version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1`

Comment: OpenSSH 6.6 should support `-T`.

Comment: Anyway, you have asked about `internal-sftp`. And wrote *"I am not asking how to fix this problem."* Now you seem to want to fix the problem. If you do, please ask a question about the problem. Your problem has nothing to do with `internal-sftp`.

Comment: Martin, OK. Thanks for your support. I doubt this may be related to OpenSSH version. OpensSSH 7.2 works fine with this setting.

Comment: Make sure you include all the information you have posted here in comments into your new question.